# Unable to understand React-native Error on my app

Tags: react-native

I have been playing to learn following a udemy tutorial with react-native. I am stuck with this error as shown on the iphone image. The code for my app is as follow: This problem happens when I go to this file where the error is shown on the app

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react' ;
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import ColorCounter from '../components/ColorCounter';

const COLOUR_COUNT = 15 ;

const reducer = (state, action)  => {

  switch (action.colorToChange) {
      case 'red':
         return { ...state, red: state.red + action.amount };
      case 'green':
        return { ...state, green: state.green + action.amount };
      case 'blue':
        return { ...state, blue: state.blue + action.amount }; 
      default:
        return state ;
   }
};

const SquareScreen = () => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0}) ;
    const [red, green, blue] = state ;

    return ( <View>
     <ColorCounter
     onIncrease={() => 
        dispatch ({ colorToChange: 'red', amount: COLOUR_COUNT}) }
     onDecrease={() => 
        dispatch ({ colorToChange: 'red', amount: -1 * COLOUR_COUNT }) } 
     color="Red" 
     />
     <ColorCounter 
     onIncrease={() => 
        dispatch ({ colorToChange: 'blue', amount: COLOUR_COUNT}) } 
     onDecrease={() => 
        dispatch ({ colorToChange: 'blue', amount: -1 * COLOUR_COUNT })}
     color="Blue"/>
     <ColorCounter 
     onIncrease={() => 
        dispatch ({ colorToChange: 'green', amount: COLOUR_COUNT})} 
     onDecrease={() => 
        dispatch ({ colorToChange: 'green', amount: -1 * COLOUR_COUNT })}
     color="Green" />

     <View
       style={{
         height: 150,
         width: 150,
         backgroundColor: `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`  
       }}
       />

    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({}) ;

export default SquareScreen;
```

The error message image that appears when I go to this code is as follows:

[React error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAOqg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Correct this:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0}) ;
const {red, green, blue} = state ;
```

The first line is an array destructuring, the second is an object one

Comment: Also, as a debug strategy, I like to go commenting pieces of code, until I can isolate the problem